# Php Mysql Classifieds list stuck

Tags: mysql, sql

bx_ads_category  (Main Categories Table)

```
ID | Name
1  | Job
9  | Property
11 | General
```

bx_ads_category_subs  (Sub Categories Table)

```
ID | IDClassified | NameSub
85 | 1            | Developer
86 | 1            | Accountant
87 | 9            | For Sale
88 | 11           | For Rent
```

bx_ads_main  (Classifieds List Table)

```
ID | IDClassifiedsSubs | Subject | etc.
10 | 85                | A Company need Php Developer
11 | 85                | B Company need Php Developer
12 | 86                | C Company need Accountant
13 | 88                | Lux Apartment
```

I need list like that

```
SELECT * FROM bx_ads_category WHERE ID = 1
```

Result

```
10 = A Company need Php Developer
11 = B Company need Php Developer
12 = C Company need Accountant
```

Comment: What is the question? Can you be more specific on what you need.

Comment: We are mind readers... I am telepathically getting the answer now...

Comment: I can't listed like
10 = A Company need Php Developer
11 = B Company need Php Developer

I need what i can use and list like that "SELECT * FROM bx_ads_category WHERE ID = 1"

Comment: *"I need list like that SELECT * FROM bx_ads_category WHERE ID = 1"*  - So, go for it.

Comment: I take it back from a question asked a few hours ago, about being the Winner of today's Totally Unclear what you're Asking prize. You get to wear the crown now.

Comment: Why in your desired output *C Company need Accountant* is not listed? It also falls under category 1.

Comment: Sorry i forgot Company C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT m.id, m.subject
  FROM bx_ads_main m JOIN bx_ads_category_subs s 
    ON m.IDClassifiedsSubs = s.ID JOIN bx_ads_category c
    ON s.IDClassified = c.ID
 WHERE c.ID = 1
```

Output:

```
| ID |                      SUBJECT |
|----|------------------------------|
| 10 | A Company need Php Developer |
| 11 | B Company need Php Developer |
| 12 |    C Company need Accountant |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5beaef/3)** demo

Answer (score 2):

I think you can have your result with a join query as follow

```
SELECT * 
FROM bx_ads_category a
INNER JOIN bx_ads_main b
ON a.IDClassifiedsSubs = b.ID
INNER JOIN bx_ads_category c
ON b.IDClassified = c.ID
WHERE c.ID = 1
```